# How to pass this command to subprocess.call?

Tags: python, subprocess

Command:

```
root@host:~#convert source.jpg -resize x500 -resize "500x<" -gravity center +repage target.jpg
```

Python code:

```
>> command_list = ['convert', 'source.jpg', '-resize', 'x500', '-resize', '\'500x<\'', '-gravity', 'center', 'target.jpg']
>> p = subprocess.call(command_list)
convert: invalid argument for option `'500x<'': -resize.
```

What's wrong in above code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why the extra quotes on `500x<`?  Subprocess will correctly quote any arguments.

Keep in mind that the shell will NOT pass the outer quotes to the application, just the quoted value, but subprocess will pass the quotes if you force it to.

Comment: More precisely, arguments don't need quoting in general -- only when you're passing a command line to the shell or system()

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `'"500x<"'` instead of `'\'500x<\''`?